# non-initialized referenced variable doesn't throw notice

Tags: php, variables, pass-by-reference

I have a function that takes a variable as a reference:

```
function get_articles($limit = 10, &$more = false){
  $results = get_results_from_db($limit); 
  $more = ($results->found > $limit) ? $results->found : false;
  return $results->data;
}
```

which I use it like:

```
$articles = get_articles(10, $more_results);

foreach($articles as $article){
  // do stuff
}

if($more_results) // we have more than 10 results
```

But I don't get a notice telling me that `$more_results` above is undefined...
Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because `$more_results` will always be defined at least with `false` value (after calling function).
Inside function variable will not be defined, but since you doesn't read content of variable, notice is not generated.

Comment: Actually null. But then a notice always thrown when you use an undefined variable depending on your error settings.

Answer (score 3):

It's normal.

Undefined variable notices are only generated for **read** accesses. When you pass a parameter by reference it's however tantamount to an implicit **write** access.

```
 $articles = get_articles(10, $more_results);
 // $more_results = NULL;  because of & here
```

The variable (unless existing) will be initialized to `NULL` prior to the function invocation in order to be able to generate a reference to that zval.

The `= false` default value of the function signature will only be assigned to its internal parameter if you don't pass a variable as second parameter. (Your example assigns it as value later still..)

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that this is the normal behaviour. Php will always create a var if the referenced var does not exist. Trying to find it now, but you can read the below article for why not to use references in php.

http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html